# How can I get "is now friends with" and "was tagged in" posts in Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am using ASP.NET and C# together with the latest Facebook SDK API from codeplex (Graph API). I would like to get all of my (the logged in user) newsfeed contents as a JSON object.
Using the "read_stream" permission, I do not get any of:

1. The "is now friends with" posts which indicate my friends have new friends. These posts appear on my news feed when in facebook.com.
2. The "X was tagged in a photo" style posts which indicate one of my friends is now tagged in a photo. These type of posts also appear on my news feed when in facebook.com.

I tried to find a way to get this data using the API's methods, using different permission types, using the FQL queries, but failed...
Can you help with that? Is there any direct way to get that data?
Thanks!

Comment: did you mean the /me/home? it is different from /me/feed

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the stories are not currently available in the "/home" or "/feed" endpoints yet. If you would like, you can file a feature request in [Bugzilla](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net). Right now, you could sort of fake the "is now friend with" story at least for the current by subscribing to the "/friends" connection of the User object using the [Real-time Updates](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) feature and keeping a log. Unfortunately, you can't yet subscribe to the "/tagged" connection using Real-time Updates so I'm afraid there's no good way I can think of to mimic those stories until we add that support.

Comment: Actually the objects in the /tagged connection contain a "created_time" so you could feasibly construct those stories as well by re-querying /tagged every so often.